# Questions about SQL server functions

Tags: sql-server

How to convert Integer(time) in to Time format.

EX : Integer(16) it has to convert into Time format as(16:00:00)

Answer (score 2):

> Angular 2

**Angular 2** comes with everything you need to build a complicated frontend web or mobile apps, form handling, data management, HTTP services, and so much more. With a rising popularity and more and more features coming to the core, the Angular team decided to rewrite the original framework, introducing Angular 2.

**Angular 2** is based entirely on components – Angular 2 is entirely component-based so that controllers and $scope are now dead. $scope will be removed in Angular 2.0 in favor of ES6 classes

Support for TypeScript— you get access to all the advantages, libraries, and technologies associated with TypeScript.

universal server rendering –

Improved Data Binding –

> Angular 4

After the release of Angular 2, the next big update for Angular was come i.e. Angular 4, Using angular 4 you can fully take advantage of all those features and start developing awesome applications immediately.

**Angular 4** has following new features –

Faster and smaller – Angular 4 is now faster and smaller!

Animations now have their own package i.e. @angular/platform-browser/animations

Templates – template is now ng-template. you should use the ng-template tag

Email Validator – In Angular 2.0, we use an email validator, using pattern option. but in Angular 4.0, there is a validator to validate an email.
Angular Universal: it’s possible to render Angular applications outside of the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot Now I got some Info about the Difference between Angular 2 and Angular4